# ¿Cómo unir dos listas en visual studio c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, lista, nodos

tengo una clase llamada alumnos y otra clase llamada lista en la clase alumnos están varias variables entre ellas una que dice calificaciones lo que quiero es que mi lista contenga todos los datos menos el de calificaciones y en otra lista que estén las calificaciones pero no se como unirlas por decirlo de algún modo.

```
class CalificacionesLista
{
    private Alumnos head1;

    public Alumnos Head1
    {
        get { return head1; }
        set { head1 = value; }
    }
    
    public CalificacionesLista()
    {
        head1 = null;
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No se entiende absolutamente nada de tu problema...

Comment: No se entiende, estas queriendo hacer una especie de Join (como harias con dos tablas en sql) con las dos listas??

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.